# $scope is not defined

Tags: html, angularjs

I must be missing something simple. I get the error $scope is not defined in plunker. Where is the error? I have declared the module, controller and dependencies I cannot see where the error is.

```
    var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [$scope]);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function () {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
     'age': 1},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 2},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 3}
  ];

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
});

    <html ng-app='phonecatApp'>
    <head>
      <title>My Angular App</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">Search: <input ng-model="query">
  Sort by:
  <select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
    <option value="age">Newest</option>
  </select>


  <ul class="phones">
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
      <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: take a look to this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/rn1apoWd9of0VHyz6SYO?p=preview

Answer (score 7):

You have to inject `$scope` in your controller declaration

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
```

Minification safe version:

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
```

Comment: I've been testing in IE and Chrome and this just resolved an error I spent about five hours working on for both browsers. I had to use the minification-safe version, but I don't know why it works. Can you help me understand what's going on in your answer?

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters - This explains it better than I can in a comment: http://frontendcollisionblog.com/javascript/angularjs/2015/03/31/something-no-one-tells-you-about-minifying-angularjs-controllers-until-its-too-late.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response to a new comment on such an old question. This article looks very promising!

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters - No problem! Glad ya figured out the issue

Answer (score 1):

try to inject the scope in the controller:

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
     'age': 1},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 2},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 3}
  ];

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
});
```

it would be better if you define your controller followed by your module declaration as follows:

```
angular.module('phonecatApp').controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', 
function($scope) {
}]);
```

working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/rn1apoWd9of0VHyz6SYO?p=preview

Comment: Even something as simple as this does not work. Is it something to do with plunker?http://plnkr.co/edit/M98A0QUdc2NPG0tu9NYr?p=preview

Comment: your script should be after the angular dependency